# Rails3 / Sessions / Active_Record_Store / Signout --> How to delete the cookie and the record in the Sessions table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, cookies

Using active_record_store to store information relating to my users' sessions, and having a great time with how easy it is, but also finding that it is so easy that I am not taking the time to understand it.

I recently found that when users sign out of my site, nothing in the Sessions table is deleted, and so I have very quickly amassed a rather large Sessions table.

**What I'd like to do is:** Delete the record in the Sessions table when the user signs out AND delete the cookie on the user's computer.  What do I have to add to my signout routine to accomplish this?

As of now, all that I'm doing is wiping the user id from the session data, which is clearly not sufficient.  I thought I could just delete the record from Sessions by calling the destroy() method on the ActiveRecord object, but, I don't have the session ID.  (Maybe I just don't know how to get it?)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a freshman of rails,but i suggest you try this :

```
rake db:sessions:clear
```

Comment: that would clear all sessions, not those of users when the log out!

Answer (score 0):

Only because this is the top answer on google when searching for "rails active_record_store clear table", here is the answer on how to clear the sessions-table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10088725/1474934

Answer (score -1):

```
 session[:user_id] = nil
 session[:username]= nil
 flash[:notice]= "You have been Logged out"
 redirect_to(:action => "login")
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the entry from the sessions table