# How to clear rails sessions table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I use active record store for rails sessions store.

Over just a short time, the size of `sessions` table has increased a lot. How are these session rows dumped after a certain period of time. Or should I manually clear them once in 24 hours?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A good blog post about your issue : http://blog.brightbox.co.uk/posts/clearing-out-rails-sessions

The solution is to create a custom rake task:

```
task :clear_expired_sessions => :environment do
    sql = 'DELETE FROM sessions WHERE updated_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);'
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

... and run it every day with a cron job.

Comment: The Postgres equivalent:  `sql = "DELETE FROM sessions WHERE updated_at < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 days');"`

Comment: That's great. I would also recommend keeping your sessions in a nosql db rather than there. Perhaps Redis. Hitting the actual DB is too expensive of a trip

Answer (score 35):

Use a standard call to ActiveRecord in Rails 3.2. For the date, pass a value that matches the length of your "Remember me" duration. In my example, this will clear ALL sessions that have been inactive for two weeks.

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.delete_all(["updated_at < ?", 2.weeks.ago])
```

As stated by @journeyer below, if using the Devise gem, one can reference the Devise' configuration.

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.delete_all(["updated_at < ?", Devise.remember_for.ago])
```

If using the Sorcery gem, one can reference the Sorcery's configuration.

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.delete_all(["updated_at < ?", User.sorcery_config.remember_me_for.ago])
```

Comment: If you using Devise, you can get the remember_for duration with `Devise.remember_for`                                                                              `ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.delete_all(["updated_at < ?", Devise.remember_for])`

Comment: Sorry, the above should be:   ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.delete_all(["updated_at < ?", Devise.remember_for.ago])

Comment: Session Cookies and Persistent Cookies are different and shouldn't be compared. The `Devise.remember_for` time period is for a persistent cookie and is not the session (which exists whether you are logged in or not).  It defaults to 2 weeks, but could be years.  Sessions on the other hand only last until you close your browser.  2 weeks is plenty.

Comment: I'm not actively using rails, so can someone mention please where this one-liner should exist at?

Answer (score 7):

When you call `reset_session` rails will delete that row from the session table. However not every session will have `reset_session` called on it: if a user closes their browser without logging out then the browser will discard the session cookie, so that session row will never be used again, but `reset_session` won't be called.

Rails won't clear out that accumulating cruft for you - it's up to you to do any housekeeping on it as you see fit. In a previous job we use to run a cronjob that deleted old session rows.

Comment: This is correct.  If you remove your session cookie in the browser, that session row will also be left in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Don't run SQL. There's a rake task for this already.

```bash
bin/rake db:sessions:trim
```

Running `bin/rake db:sessions:trim` will delete all sessions that have not
been updated in the last 30 days.

See rails docs.
https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store/blob/master/README.md?plain=1#L31-L36

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend clearing your rails sessions using a cron job or something.  Maybe not 24 hours tho, depends on how long you want user sessions available for.  Rails provides a rake task for this

> rake db:sessions:clear

Comment: AFAIK this task also drops the active sessions.

Comment: Correct, this rake task will drop ALL sessions

Comment: this could be harmful do not use it.