# Rails session record not deleted from sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I see that when I click logout, I set the session variables to NIL and call reset_session. I see that the entry from the SQL DB is not deleted on this (but the session looks to get invalidated).

I see that though the entry in SQL is not deleted for the session id, the data in the session gets changed on executing the destroy call.

```
def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    reset_session
end
```

I am running on rails 3.2.13. The destroy does not remove the entry from SQL:

```
mysql> select * from sessions;
+-----+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id  | session_id                       | data                                                                                   | created_at          | updated_at          |
+-----+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 155 | e5e458c3dc93fd34193984b02790c2bf | BAh7BiIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMStlQXoycTVwWi9BZDRNNlZwZmhIYURITG1q
cmgyN0lSTHFzYjFQY3UzZmM9
 | 2014-07-29 21:54:55 | 2014-07-29 21:54:55 |
+-----+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the implementation of `reset_session` ?

Comment: This is rails implemented function I believe. The code from API doc:

Comment: sorry. couldn't get the implementation from it. But then "http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html" says it should clean up state. Won't the sql data be cleaned up ?

Comment: The `reset_session` you use will clear the session between the end-user and your app. It is not linked to anything to your database. You have to clear the session_id in the DB manually

Comment: Since the datastore is created and maintained by rails, shouldn't be cleaning it up ? I really doubt if we have to clear it manually.

Comment: From another thread "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088619/how-to-clear-rails-sessions-table" When you call reset_session rails will delete that row from the session table. However not every session will have reset_session called on it: if a user closes their browser without logging out then the browser will discard the session cookie, so that session row will never be used again, but reset_session won't be called.

Rails won't clear out that accumulating cruft for you - it's up to you to do any housekeeping on it as you see fit.