# How to clear old/stale sessions when using Mongo DB session storage in Ruby on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, session

The Ruby on Rails application I have inherited is working well, but uses MongoDB for session storage. And the sessions collection table has not been cleared in 2+ years (!!!) which means it is filled with over 2 million entries which take up about 4GB (!!!) of space. That’s not good, not needed and an incredible misuse of space for a database that is—as a whole—a lot smaller than 4GB.

So investigating how to clean this stuff up I have come across numerous posts on various sites—Stack Overflow and others—that explain the general process:

- [Cleaning the sessions database store with a rake task in Rails](http://www.erikjacobs.com/2008/12/24/cleaning-the-sessions-database-store-with-a-rake-task-in-rails/)
- [Clearing out Rails Sessions](http://blog.brightbox.co.uk/posts/clearing-out-rails-sessions)
- [How to clear rails sessions table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088619/how-to-clear-rails-sessions-table)
- [Rails: clear old sessions stored in database](http://maxivak.com/rails-clear-old-sessions-stored-in-database/)

Which makes sense: Create a `rake` task that connects to `sessions` and removes entries based on `updated_at` criteria. All good!

The problem in my case is this Ruby on Rails application uses [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org) and [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/) so none of the examples provided on those pages is actually helpful. So something like this won’t work:

```
namespace :sessions do
  desc "Clear expired sessions (more than 7 days old)"
  task :cleanup => :environment do
    ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.delete_all(["updated_at < ?", 7.days.ago])
  end
end
```

The application does not use ActiveRecord, so no dice. The `rake` task dies with ActiveRecord not being there and dies if ActiveRecord is included since core DB logic is not hinged on ActiveRecord models; it’s all Mongoid.

Also using the supposedly baked-in `rake db:sessions:clear` some people recommend doesn’t seem to work which I believe is connected to the app not using ActiveRecord, thus that task doesn’t even exist.

How would I be able to create an equivalent query using Mongoid in Rails 3 to clear out clearly dead, old and stale sessions from DB session storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to solving this is understanding that using direct [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/) methods when your Rails 3 application’s `session_store` is set to `mongoid_store` would never allow this kind of direct database interaction to happen.

So instead, by using Mongoid just for the basic database connection but then actually interacting with the [Moped](http://mongoid.org/en/moped/) core of Mongoid directly on a driver operation level, the same functionality can be achieved with ease! Here is the Mongoid/Moped `rake` task I came up with that works quite well:

```
namespace :sessions do
  stale_window = 7
  desc "Clear stale DB sessions older than #{ stale_window } days."
  task :cleanup => :environment do
    db = Mongoid::Sessions.default
    begin
      db[:sessions].where('updated_at' => { '$lt' => stale_window.days.ago }).sort(updated_at: 1).no_timeout.remove_all
    rescue Moped::Errors::SocketError => e
      # Rescue here if needed. If not, the screwed up process dies silently.
    end
  end
end
```

The connection is set via `db = Mongoid::Sessions.default` and the magic happens in the line:

```
db[:sessions].where('updated_at' => { '$lt' => stale_window.days.ago }).sort(updated_at: 1).no_timeout.remove_all
```

I have set a `stale_window` variable so I can easily adjust the range of this task; sets the DB value as well as the description. To use it I run it like this from the codebase path:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sessions:cleanup
```

And of course just change the `RAILS_ENV` value to match the environment you wish this task to act on; such as `staging`, `development` or whatever else you might name your environment. After running that `rake` task, the `sessions` collection table gets pruned to something more realistic with real-world usage and the overall database size is more reasonable to deal with.