# Clear all sessions in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

The following command doesn't work in Rails 5.0.0.beta1:

```
rake db:sessions:clear
```

What is the easiest way to clear all sessions in Rails 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to clear rails sessions table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088619/how-to-clear-rails-sessions-table)

There's a number of methods which should be still valid in rails5 and
Give you the chance not to clear active sessions.

Upgrade notes even refer to the `db:sessions:clear` command.http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

Comment: bin/rake db:sessions:clear
Running via Spring preloader in process 49871
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:sessions:clear' (see --tasks)
/Users/stefan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:296:in `load'

Comment: Is this a bug in beta1?